# How to put a regular expression ending with a dollar sign into a formula?

Tags: math-mode

i have a simple question. I have a regular expression that i want to put into my thesis like a math formula. This is the regular expression:

```
^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$
```

This worked doing it this way:

```
\[\hat{ }var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$\]
```

Now i wanted to change the style from "it" to "sc", because it's not really a formula, trying this:

```
\[\textsc{\hat{ }var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$}\]
```

But now i'm getting this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

How can i solve this little problem? Thx in advance :)

Comment: Within `\textsc{...}` LaTeX behaves very much like in normal text mode, so you will have to math-escape `\hat` like so: `\[\textsc{$\hat{\pahntom{x}}$var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$}\]` or even `\[\textsc{$\hat{\phantom{x}}$var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$}\]`; it does not look nice though and slightly goes against semantic typesetting, I think, so `verbatim` or its extensions (the `listings` package springs to mind) might be better for you.

Comment: That worked thanks, but what do you mean by semantic typesetting? In the description below i format the parameter i'm referencing just like that.

Comment: `\[...\]` are normally used to typeset maths (equations and the like), in the usage I described above `\[...\]` is only used to center the content (and number it, possibly). The same could be achieved by `\begin{center}\textsc{$\hat{\phantom{x}}$var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$}\end{center}`, here we use `center` to actually describe what we are doing (that's what I meant by "semantic typesetting": using code that *describes* what you do, and not using some construction that might happen to work but has no semantic connection to what is being done).

Comment: I forgot: With my code above you escape math mode and have to re-enter it via `$..$`, this is not necessary: replace the `\hat{..}` construct by `\^{}`, so you get `\[\textsc{\^{}var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$}\]`. But now the sole purpose of `[...]` is to center the text, and this is certainly bad practice, as `\[..\]` is for *maths*. In semantic typesetting you would define a new command such as `\newcommand*{\mycode}[1]{\begin{center}\textsc{#1}\end{center}}` and use it like so: `\mycode{\^{}var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);\$}` in the document; or use a package that does what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why math?

Use `verbatim` and instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\verb!^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$!
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: regex]

If you want to place it centered:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[b6paper,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Text before the regular expression:

\begin{center}
\verb!^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$!
\end{center}

Text after the regular expression.
\end{document}
```

Looks like:

[image: centered regex]

Comment: I don't like that typewriter style, but the main problem is that it's not centered like with those brackets.

Comment: You can change the typewriter style, that's not a problem. And what you mean by "centered"? Position on the page?

Comment: @Auberotte You are clearly trying to display source code. In my experience the *de facto* standard for source code is using type writer style. If you want it centered, try `\begin{center}\verb!blah!\end{center}` or use one of the more sophisticated environments provided by verbatim packages such as `listings` (`lstlisting`).

Comment: Exactly, i don't really want it inside my text because it's an important part of my program, so i want to highlight it and descripe it in the section below.

Comment: @moewe I have defined listings for my C++-Code but i didn't wanted to format that piece like my Code, anyways you helped me out already, so thanks :)

Comment: Another option for typesetting code is `minted` which, in my opinion, produces better output than `listings`.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `listings` package, which provides the `\lstinline` command; it's much more customizable than `\verb`. In any case I'd use a different typeface for such snippets of code; I repeat the example three times, first with the regular font, then in sans serif type and finally in typewriter type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
\begin{document}
Text before the regular expression:
\begin{center}
\verb!^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$!
\end{center}
Text between the regular expressions.
\begin{center}
\lstinline!^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$!
\end{center}
Text between the regular expressions.
\begin{center}
\lstinline[basicstyle=\sffamily]!^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$!
\end{center}
Text between the regular expressions.
\begin{center}
\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]!^var c[12]+Arr = new Array(.*);$!
\end{center}
Text after the regular expression.
\end{document}
```

[image]